# Issue with Druid SQL and Curl

Tags: sql, druid

I making curl SQL queries against a druid broker and whenever I use a WHERE clause such as in

```
curl -kv -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql?pretty --data '{"query" : "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE \"TABLE_NAME\"=\"myTable\""}'
```

I'm having this same error:

```
Column 'myTable' not found in any table","errorClass":"org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException"
```

But I can verify it is there. If I don't use the where clause, I can see:

```
...    {
    "TABLE_CATALOG": "druid",
    "TABLE_SCHEMA": "druid",
    "TABLE_NAME": "apim_metrics",
    "COLUMN_NAME": "myTable",
    "ORDINAL_POSITION": "0",
    "COLUMN_DEFAULT": "",
    "IS_NULLABLE": "NO",
    "DATA_TYPE": "TIMESTAMP",
    "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": null,
    "CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH": null,
    "NUMERIC_PRECISION": null,
    "NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX": null,
    "NUMERIC_SCALE": null,
    "DATETIME_PRECISION": "3",
    "CHARACTER_SET_NAME": null,
    "COLLATION_NAME": null,
    "JDBC_TYPE": 93
}, ...
```

I think I have exhausted all combination of ", \", ' ... and it does not work.

Thanks for your help.
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes instead:

```
WHERE \"TABLE_NAME\"='myTable'
```

That should make Druid treat `myTable` as a string instead of a column name.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried and it does not work (I believe shell is mixing things). The solution that I just found: put the query in a file ({"query" : "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='myTable'"} and refer this file in curl (-d@file) and it works.